# Unable to retrieve value from url

Tags: javascript, liferay

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function popupCreation(objct) {

        <% popupURL.setParameter("resourceKey", newVideoCode); %>

        var URL = '<%=popupURL%>';

        var jspPageUrl = '<%=popupURL%>';

        jspPageUrl = jspPageUrl + '&resourceKeyyy=';

        jspPageUrl = jspPageUrl + objct;

        alert(jspPageUrl);



        AUI().use('liferay-util-window', 'aui-io-deprecated', function (A) {

            modal = Liferay.Util.openWindow({

                dialog: {

                    id: 'discountpage',
                    centered: true,    
                    modal: true,    
                    width: 550,    
                    height: 50,

                },

                uri: URL

            });

        });
    }
</script>

<% 
  PortletURL popupURL=r enderResponse.createRenderURL(); 
  popupURL.setWindowState(LiferayWindowState.POP_UP); 
  System.out.println("dsfdsfdsp;fdpp------=--"+popupURL); 
  popupURL.setParameter("jspPage", "/html/viewvideoprice/details.jsp"); 
%>
```

---

I am retrieving value in 2nd jsp as

```
String resourceKey=ParamUtil.getString(request, "resourceKey");

//System.out.println("x is >>" +resourceKey);

String currentCompleteUrl = PortalUtil.getCurrentCompleteURL(request);

System.out.println("currentCompleteUrl: "+currentCompleteUrl);

String[] partURL = currentCompleteUrl.split("&");

String currentURL = themeDisplay.getURLCurrent();

System.out.println(request.getContextPath());

String url = request.getRequestURI();

System.out.println(url);
```

Comment: Which parameter you are not able to get?

Comment: Please explain a little in more detail as to how the second JSP is called, what value you want to fetch and is the url being printed as you want it to. Thanks

Comment: jspPageUrl = jspPageUrl + objct;   Here I am passing objct that value I cannot able to find in 2nd jsp

Comment: Can you give an example URL which shows how the `objct` is appended to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Most probable reason is that your forgot to prefix your parameter with `<portlet:namespace />`.

Liferay adds the namespaces automatically when you are generating the URL's with portlet:renderURL for example so that it would know which parameter is for which portlet and so you could use the parameter "page" in multiple portlets on the same page with different values.

If you want to attach parameters to the URL in Javascript then prefix them with `<portlet:namespace />` as ParamUtil is looking for parameters that have the proper namespace.